# school assignment shell programming

Tags: linux, shell

So here's the program I am supposed to code:

***Find the even multiples of any number chosen by the user in a given range the user should specify
the multiples of which number they want to print and a minimum and maximum value.
The multiples printed should be within the [minimum, maximum] range.
For example, if the user chooses the number 7 and would like to print all even multiples in the [15, 60] range, the program should print all the even multiples that are bigger than or equal to 15 (minimum), but smaller than or equal to 60 (maximum).
The program should keep a count of how many numbers
were printed and should output that count, as well as the numbers.
The output then, for the example given, should be 28, 42, 56, and the count should be 3.***

And this is where I am:

```
read -p "What number do you want to multiply: " i
read -p "Input the minimum and maximum range: " min max

while [ $i -le $max ] && [ $i -ge $min ]
do
    echo " $i "
    ((a++))

done
```

I don't know where to go from this!!

Comment: You probably want to increment `i`, not `a`.

Comment: Also, check the modulo operator `%`.

Comment: What does the % do exactly?

Comment: It's the remainder, e.g. `17 % 5 == 2`.